# Issues with content hiding behind fixed position nav-bar

Tags: css, html, flexbox

I've been learning HTML5/CSS of late, and a little bit of Flexbox too.
With that in mind, I've been trying to put together a responsive page, nothing overly complicated, that has fixed navigation in bother header and footer.

```
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/addycoder/pen/zJeewm)
```

When the viewport is > 700px, I just force the  down 73px so that it's not hiding behind the nav. But < 700px, the header obviously expands, and no matter what I try, I can't seem to get a clean solution to the content not being hidden as the header wraps and grows larger

With that in mind (as the pen shows), I change position to relative for > 700px and zero out the  margin, which gets it all in view, but loses the fixed nav.

Any ideas on where I've gone wrong. It's bound to be something simple.

First time user btw, thanks for the help

Comment: for screen width > 700 px, set margin-top for whole page equal to the height of fixed navBar

Comment: yes, I can do that, and it works, but the height of the nav bar (when on a mobile device, changes height, so how do I account for that as well?

Comment: Do you set fixed height for navbar in  mobile and desktop version or let it expand dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I've resolved it for the time being. Pen above updated and it seems to do what I want. I've got one media query to allow for devices < 700px and I've just used dev tools to work out the height, on the assumption that won't really change.